# Using SDL_image in Visual studio 2010, with error "application was unable to start correctly 0xc000007b"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, sdl

I'm trying to do the SDL tutorial here http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson03/windows/msvsnet2010e/index.php

I did everything they asked me to do, everything built correctly, but when I tried to run the executable, I always get the error: "application was unable to start correctly 0xc000007b"

I'm using Win7 on a mac (bootcamp), with visual stdio 2010 professional

Answer (score 9):

If you have placed SDL.dll under `C:\Windows\system32` or `\SysWOW64` like the tutorial says, doing this may work:

[Download **SDL.dll**](http://www.libsdl.org/download-1.2.php) (Runtime Libraries > Win32, **not** the 64-bit version*) and place it in the project folder where the .exe file is located.

E.g. if the project location is `C:\myproject`, place the SDL.dll at `C:\myproject\Debug`.

Then you can remove SDL.dll from `\system32` or `\SysWOW64`. This can also prevent version conflicts, like the tutorial suggests.

<sup>*) I'm on 64-bit Windows 7, and the 64-bit version of SDL.dll didn't work for me.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the SDL.dll (or SDL2.dll) that the .exe loads (from its own directory, or from a Windows system directory) matches the SDL.lib that it was linked with.  Examples:

- [The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492037/the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc000007b)
- [Dev IL linking and compiling error (0xc000007b)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27180403/dev-il-linking-and-compiling-error-0xc000007b)

This applies to any version of Visual Studio, 32 or 64 bit, and any of Lazyfoo's tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Also what helped me - ensure you are using x86 .dll for the x86 application and not x64 dll files for the x86 app and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue in VS2019 when running in debug mode, had to add path to my debugging environment.

[Project properties->debugging settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDLZl.png)