# glew32.dll error in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: dll, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, glew

This problem is pretty self explanatory. Here are the details: I'm trying to include freeglut and glew in Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8. I'm on a 64 bit system, so I thought I needed to put glew32.dll in my 64 bit system folder. I tried that and receive the following error:

"The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application."

Which I've interpreted as I'm trying to put a 32 bit dll in the 64 bit folder or vice-versa.

Just for laughs, I tried putting the file in System32, but of course, it just told me the file wasn't on my computer. Any suggestions?

EDIT* May I also add that some of the set up for this was NOT the same as it would have been on Windows 7 or Visual Studio 2010 or earlier. I may have missed something because I kind of winged it using the search function combined with some documentation I found on various websites. (i.e the lib and include folders are no longer in the same place)

EDIT2* I'm sure this can probably be derived, but I want to add it anyway for clarity: If I removed the dependency for glew32.lib and comment out any code using glew.h, the window forms as it should. I don't think my source code is needed seeing as I'm 99% sure this is not a code issue, but if anyone wants to see it, let me know and I'll attach it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492037/the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc000007b)

Comment: I'll try that when I get home from work. Thanks for the reference. I'll update around 6 PM CST.

Comment: So, I knew from the beginning that it was an issue with a .dll dependency, but I think it has to do with Windows 8 and/or Visual Studio 2012. I'm downloading the latest dlls from http://glew.sourceforge.net/, and I am double checking that I am grabbing the 64 bit folder. As I stated originally, I know that it is 64 bit because when I place the dll in the 32 bit folder, Visual Studio just doesn't see it. The error happens when I place it in the 64 bit folder. There may actually be no solution to this yet seeing as Windows 8 is fairly new. Just wishful thinking. :/

Comment: Ok. So I got around to using Dependency Walker, it shows the parent .dll file as being x64, but then it shows some of the child .dll files under it as being x86. Would this be causing the issue, and if so, how do I fix it?