# error in compiling c++ code using MSBuild from command prompt

Tags: c++, windows-7, msbuild

I have multiple c++ projects with inter dependency. To compile them together I made a batch script. I used below command to compile

```
 MSBuild.exe "xyz.sln" /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /t:REBUILD /fileLogger /p:DebugSymbols=true /nr:true
```

All projects were getting compiled few months back, but now when I am trying to build them from command prompt build is failing and I am getting dialog box with message

```
Application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application.
```

and build is failing with below error.

```
(ClCompile target) ->C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\x64\Microsoft.Cpp
.x64.Targets(146,5): error MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code -1073741701.
```

But if I try to compile projects from visual studio 2010 then project is getting compiled successfully.

Is this problem anywhere related to windows updates?

My operating system is Windows7 and application is 64bit. Build is failing in both Debug and Release mode with x64 configuration.

Can anyone suggest a solution for it?

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492037/the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc000007b

Comment: tried looking for that. but did not solved the problem. unable to find which dll is missing from dependency walker

Answer (score 0):

Is the PATH set right in the process that runs the bat file?  Sometimes installing software changes the path and I've found commonly named DLLs being found from the wrong app.