# Setting up SDL in Visual Studio with Errors

Tags: c++

I have been having this issue for a very long time, I have not even had no luck and it is becoming very frustrating. I am really itching to create games in `C++` with `OpenGL/SDL`. I am using `Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012`. My Operating System is a **64-bit** Windows 7.

I had no troubles setting up OpenGL with Visual Studio, but `SDL` is the main problem. I follow lazy foo tutorials, I looked at YouTube videos, god damn it is irritating. The error I am getting when debugging SDL in Visual Studio is:

> 1>SDLMain.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _SDL_Init
>   referenced in function _SDL_main 1>SDLMain.obj :
>  error LNK2019:
>   unresolved external symbol _SDL_Quit referenced in function _SDL_main
>   1>MSVCRT.lib(crtexew.obj) : 
>  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   *WinMain@16 referenced in function _*_tmainCRTStartup

Comment: Did you link with SDL library file by specifying the name of the lib file in the project settings? Also from what I have checked, the available development libraries from the main website for win32 are built for eariler versions of Visual C++ (version 6,7,8 and 9). Since you are using Visual Studio 2012, which is version 11, you should download the SDL source and build the SDL library yourself using VS2012 instead.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what you mean by building the libraries by myself, but I did link the SDL Library. I switched from x64 to x86 and when I debugged my code again I got this message:

The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application.

So your saying if I downloaded an earlier version of Visual studio, I can run SDL without a problem?

Comment: Now it has turned into a runtime error just by switching the target platform from x64 to x86? Seems like a mismatch of target platform in the dependent libraries i.e. the SDL library you are using is compiled targeting x64 while your project is targeting x86 hence a 32-bit application trying to load a 64-bit dll or even a mixed-up of system library files for 64-bit and 32-bit applications. Maybe this related question will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492037/the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc000007b