# gdb fails when using with mingw

Tags: gdb, mingw

I'm trying to use gdb from the command line within MinGW but it keeps crashing.  Whenever I type *gdb.exe* or *gdb* or even *gdb exampleprogram.exe*, it crashes and I get a windows popup stating "The application was unable to start correctly (0xC000007b).  Click OK to close the application".  I don't have the slightest clue how to diagnose this problem.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Install Dependency Walker (like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492037/the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc000007b) and open gdb.exe in it. Check if all dependent dll are present.

Comment: It looks like gdb is 32-bit and it's trying to load 64-bit dlls.  How can I get a copy of LIBEXPAT-1.DLL and LIBINTL-8.DLL?

Comment: UPDATE:  I found out that these are installed with a base MinGW install but maybe they were corrupt?  I just installed MinGW to a different directory and copied over both files and gdb opens just fine!  Thanks for the suggestion.