# Error : the application was unable to start correctly

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, dll, console-application

Can anyone tell me what causes this error:

[image]

I don't know what other information about the project may be needed to be included!
If you need more information, it would be appreciated to inform me.
But please help me!

---

I'm running the program on a Win7x64 ultimate and this is the configuration of my project:

[image]

also these are the paths of include and library directories that are needed in the project:
[image]
[image]
the program uses `OpenGL`,`GLU`,`GLUT` and `GDAL/OGR` libraries, which I have downloaded GDAL/OGR from [here](http://www.gisinternals.com/sdk/PackageList.aspx?file=release-1600-gdal-1-10-mapserver-6-2.zip).
Also I need these dlls in my program:

```
gdal110.dll
glut32.dll
libexpat.dll
xerces-c_2_8.dll
libpq.dll
ssleay32.dll
```

that I have copied and pasted them from the path below ( which I have provided from the downloaded folders in my program )

```
D:\JobList\Lib\GDAL_lib\x86\bin
```

next to the .exe file of my project.
This is too late to try all the ways you've suggested, I will try all ofd them tomorrow but please don't close my question and just tell me what I'm doing wrong in asking the question.
thanks for your attention!

**Oh, and one more thing is that this program was runnin perfectly. But recently I have reinstalled my windows and the above problem is created after reinstallin the windows.**

Comment: FWIW in the past, that may come from trying to mix 32 and 64 bits environments. Try to make sure you're using the correct version for your `.dll`s for example.

Comment: That is STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT.  Just a few causes for that.  Having an implicit dependency on a DLL that contains 32-bit code when your program is 64-bit, or the other way around.  Or trying to run a program on Windows XP that's marked to be only compatible with later Windows versions.

Answer (score 1):

Use Dependency Walker tool to make sure there are no DLLs missed. Take a look here: [The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492037/the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc000007b)

Comment: well @Yury Schkatula can dependency walker be used for visual c++ codes?

Comment: Dependency Walker operates regardless the language origin (C++, VB whatever) because it checks "import tables": first of all EXE import table, then recursively all import tables from all DLLs involved into the dependency tree.