# Cannot Open Python. Error 0xc000007b

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

I have recently been learning Python 3. I have had no problems on my netbook (32bit Windows 7) I with creating small simple programs. When I installed it on my netbook I had no problems, but now that I've been getting into it I want to install it on my desktop and I have one. 
My desktop is a 64 bit OS running Windows 7. Like I did with my netbook, I went to download Python and install the 64 bit edition.

After installing it, I went to open up Python CLI and GUI and no luck. It gave me this error.

```
"The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application"
```

I also tried reinstalling, but not luck.

I suspect a missing .dll but I am not completely sure. Does anyone know what is keeping me from opening Python and how do I fix it?. I want to resume my work as soon as possible.

Comment: Python depends on C++ runtime libraries; you could try if installing [Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14632) helps.

Comment: Note that you should be able to install the 32-bit version too.

Comment: @JanneKarila Thanks. Installing the 2015 edition worked for me with python 3.5.1.

Comment: @Zero3 For me also! Seems like Python's dependencies are C++ runtime libraries and SP1 for Microsoft Windows (KB976932).

Comment: Please select an answer if they worked for your problem, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

That is the `NTSTATUS` error code for `STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT`. Almost invariably that means that the loaded is attempting to link a 32 bit DLL into a 64 bit process, or vice versa.

If you want to attempt to debug this then the tool of choice is Dependency Walker. You open the python.exe executable file in Dependency Walker and use the profile menu to start it up with logging of the load events. Somewhere along the way there will be a failure and you'll be able to see which module is causing that failure. That will hopefully point the way towards a resolution.

However, attempting to debug this may be a waste of time. It will probably better to uninstall the existing installation, and try to re-install. Perhaps picking a different Python distribution.

I note that you have selected a 64 bit version. Now, support for 64 bit extension modules is not as strong on 64 bit Python as on 32 bit Python. It does exist, but they modules can be harder to come by and install. You might consider installing a 32 bit Python next time round.

Comment: If still the same problem persists, try to download the required binary from https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/ and add PYTHON environment variable with the downloaded folder path

Answer (score 6):

Please make sure that Python3.dll is the same version and the same architecture (32/64) with python.exe. I fixed this error via replacing it with 32bit version.

Comment: How do you check the version and architecture of a .dll file ?

Answer (score 3):

you should delete the old path of python in "Environment Variables" and enjoy ;)

Comment: Worked for me with deleting the old path and reinstalling.

Answer (score 2):

As [janne-karila](https://stackoverflow.com/users/222914/janne-karila) mentioned, and for [Python 3.5](https://docs.python.org/3.5/using/windows.html#compiling-python-on-windows), Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 [redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145&751be11f-ede8-5a0c-058c-2ee190a24fa6=True) (in this case the 64 bit version)

Answer (score 2):

This probably won't answer your question, but my answer is for a very specific case when you "Refresh Windows without affecting Files" to fix your Windows 8.1 PC.

If you do that, You'd get this error when you try to run Python after the windows refresh.

To fix this error, simply re-install PY at the same folder where your python was install before you refreshed windows. If you try to install it any other folder like username/appdata/... folder the PY installer would be stuck in initialization.

You may also get another error saying "api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is missing". To fix, go to the windows.old folder and get the dll file ith the above name and paste it in the PY folder. Also like others have suggested, make sure Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 redistributable is installed.

Encountering this error after a windows refresh is so rare, that no one else seemed to have experienced according to google searches, so I though I share it here for that rare unlucky person.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the error code stands for `STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT` ([source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/96035692-9a50-40d4-a7d3-48bda87d11ec/the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc000007b-click-ok-to-close-the-application-when?forum=vssetup)), and it looks like it's not specific to Python. You can try reinstalling the program, rebooting, running `CHKDSK /r` ([source](http://www.reviversoft.com/blog/2013/11/how-to-solve-the-0xc000007b-unable-to-start-error/)). It might also have something to do with the Microsoft Visual C++ redistributable package, as Janne Karila and [this thread](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/43092-63-application-unable-start-correctly-0xc000007b) suggest.

This [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10492037/1298153) also looks like it has some useful information.

Answer (score 1):

I too faced this problem. So I uninstalled python3 64-bit version and installed 32-bit version, after that i am able to launch python3 in windows 8 successfully. (i have a 64-bit laptop).

Answer (score 1):

Simply, download the last version of Microsoft Visual C++ redistributable package ..

I had the same problem ..

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error found. Using dependency walker, I found tons of DLLs missing. Rather going for copying all the DLLs I went with virtual environment. It will create another environment for Python.

First, install python normally. Copy, the Python.exe path. In my case, it is

```
C:\Python\python
```

It will be used to install Python libraries. Then, using command prompt, I used pip to download and install virtualenv (Virtual environment). To do that, change the directory to where pip.exe is, which is in Scripts folder. Now, run the following to install virtualenv:

```
C:\Python\python pip install virtualenv
```

It will install Virtual environment.

Now, create a folder to hold virtual environment and change directory to that folder and run to create the following to create an environment:

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages [environment name]
```

It will create the Environment.

Now, change subdirectory to Scripts in the [environment name] folder. There is a activate file run it, in my case it is like:

```
C:\Python\virtualenv\env\Scripts activate
```

env is the [environment name] here.

If you activate it, every command will look like:

```
(env) C:\Python\python
```

This ends here. Now, you can install any python library using this. Do whatever, you want using Python.

Also, to  deactivate the environment same deactivate.bat is in the scripts folder.

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was, I had installed 32 bit version on a 64 bit machine. Hope it helps someone out there.

Comment: That by itself is okay though

Answer (score 0):

Like many have said, Windows cannot load python.exe itself or one of its dependent DLLs because of `INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT`:

- python.exe is of unsupported bitness. 32bit on 64bit Windows is supported. 64bit on 32bit system is not (solution: install 32bit python, bye).
- python.exe or one of its DLLs is corrupted (probably not)
- one of the dependent DLLs is not of the same bitness as the EXE:

  1. python.exe (say, 32bit) requires python*.dll (python3.dll or python27.dll). It installs that into Windows `System32`/`SysWOW64` folder. The DLL is of correct bitness (32bit).
  2. Something else overwrites that with 64-bit version, or places a 64-bit version somewhere in the search `PATH`.
  3. When you run python.exe (32bit), Windows searches for python*.dll, and the first one it founds is the 64bit one. 32bit EXEs cannot <sub>normally</sub> load 64bit DLLs.

Typical examples:

- TortoiseHg installs its own copy of python (both .exe and .dll) into its own folder and adds itself to `PATH`. The bitness can be different (say, 64bit) and usually matches platform bitness.
- Another installation of Python with a different bitness somewhere else overwrites the DLL (it shouldn't, they have different `System32`s, but who knows)

Diagnostics:

- [Dependency Walker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_Walker) marks 64bit DLLs with 64bit icons. Verify that icons for `python.exe` and `python*.dll` match. Right click -> "Show full paths" to see where the DLL is taken from.

Simple solutions:

1. Maybe you have another, functioning copy of Python somewhere else? Check it.
2. Reinstall Python, preferably in the platform version (64bit for 64bit OS, 32bit for 32bit) Yeah, that's what many are saying, but now you know why this is needed.
3. Remove offenders from `PATH`. While this maaaay fix your Python, this will break the offenders and some (TortoiseHg explorer plugins) need the `PATH`. So maybe compromise with them and choose #2.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was installing both the 32 and 64 bit versions of the python msi.  They both install to the same folder, c:\python32.  I thought msi's would prevent those kinds of conflicts, but no.