# Windows .exe created with cx_Freeze returns 0xc000007b error

Tags: python, cmd, cx-freeze

I created a small script to test cx_Freeze, shown below:

**sqrt.py:**

```
import math
sqrt = math.sqrt
x = float(input('Enter a number:'))
y = sqrt(x)
print(y)
input('Press ENTER to exit')
```

I also created a setup script:

**setup.py:**

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(  name = "sqrt",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "Testing",
        # options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("sqrt.py")])
```

Next, I launch Windows cmd.exe in the folder where python.exe, sqrt.py and setup.py are located and enter:

> path\python.exe setup.py build

As it should, this creates a build directory, which contains amongst others a sqrt.exe. When I attempt to execute this, it returns

> "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK
>   to close the application."

For as far as I understand the cx_Freeze documentation, this should work. Ditto for various YouTube tutorials I've watched.

I'm running Windows10 64x, Python 3.5 and cx_freeze 5.0.

Comment: What versions of Windows?

Comment: @Soviut added to post. Windows 10.

Comment: Have you seen this related question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20650596/cannot-open-python-error-0xc000007b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the exe file created with cx_freeze with [dependencywalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

It will show you what's wrong.

Maybe you are missing a library like [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Package](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#microsoft-visual-c-redistributable-package) or you mix 32 and 64 bit architecture.

The tool will show what's wrong.

Update: I had this issue while I tried to get gtk running on windows. There were any strange things. I switched from gtk to pyside2 (QT) and things are much easier now.