# Python 3.5 64bit on Windows 8.1 64bit, The only way to install TensorFlow binaries on Windows does not work

Tags: windows, python-3.x, installation, tensorflow

Is it possible to install Python 3.5.x on Windows 8.1?
The primary goal is to install TensorFlow directly on my Windows.

It is not working. More specifically when using a 64 bit windows, and naturally trying the 64bits Python. The AMD name in the installation file is confusing, since my laptop is an Intel. But that is the only 64 bit option so I select that.

I try to set up via binaries. In the middle of installation a GUI tells me installation failed:

[image: The Error Message]

BTW, I have done my best to remove any remaining Python 32 bits from my system.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: If you were [somewhat more specific](/help/mcve) on what problems you're facing, we'd probably be able to tell more.

Comment: Sure, I will elaborate more by editing my question.

Comment: Did you download `Windows x86-64 executable installer`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I  downloaded python-3.5.3-amd64.exe. So yes.

Comment: Possibly relevent: [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20650596/cannot-open-python-error-0xc000007b)

Comment: If you're overwriting an existing 32-bit Python 3.5, then you should have uninstalled and removed the directory beforehand to get a clean install.

Comment: I have uninstalled all existing Python's via Windows Uninstall many times.  But looks like some dependencies are not fixed yet or so?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot Open Python. Error 0xc000007b](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20650596/cannot-open-python-error-0xc000007b)

Comment: Python 3.5 keeps its installed DLL dependencies (python35.dll, python3.dll, and vcruntime140.dll) in the installation directory. Unlike prior versions, an all-users install does not install anything in System32. The Universal C Runtime is there (e.g. ucrtbase.dll), but that's an OS component. Either something is being left behind from a previous install, or the Universal CRT is installed wrong. In case it's the latter, try installing [KB3118401](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3118401) for Windows 8.1 x64.

Comment: How can I make sure nothing is left from past installation? I can install 32 bit python but not 64 bit. The uninstall seems to finish properly.

Comment: I suggest `procmon` from the sysinternals suite. You'll see both which module fails to load and if the correct `python.exe` is being started (in case you happen to have another installation on `PATH`).

Comment: @eryksun It looks like the CRT is the problem actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running windows update, I finally managed to install python 3.5 64 bits and then tensorflow on my windows 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

Gooogling "python supported windows versions" brings up [Using Python on Windows — Python 3.5.3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html)<sup>1</sup>:

> ### 3.1.1. Supported Versions
>
> As specified in [PEP 11](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0011), a Python release only supports a Windows
>   platform while Microsoft considers the platform under extended
>   support. This means that Python 3.5 supports Windows Vista and newer.
>   If you require Windows XP support then please install Python 3.4.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Or rather, https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html from which you can switch to the 3.5's version of the article with the drop-down list in the upper-left corner</sub>

Comment: Is it true that tensorFlow only works with 64bit as opposed to 32 bit Pyhton, if we want to install it directly?

Comment: @user25004 at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tensorflow/1.1.0rc1 , there are only 64-bit precompiled versions as there are at https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow . Theoretically, you can compile for 32 bit from source (my guess is that it isn't worth the effort though).

Comment: I see. Thank you!