# Python unable to start correctly ( 0xc0000005)

Tags: python-3.x

i just install python 3.7 and also config the path.but when i type python in cmd its showing me "the application is unable to start correctly 0xc0000005"

The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000005).click ok to close the Application

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot Open Python. Error 0xc000007b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20650596/cannot-open-python-error-0xc000007b)

Answer (score 1):

For me, this happened because ordinary users didn't have read+execute access on the following file:

1. C:\Windows\SysWOW64\api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll

This was discovered by running Sysinternals' Process Monitor to see what the Python3 thread was doing.

HTH

Comment: could you describe the exact steps you used to improve your answer? thanks!