# How do I do to solve the 0xc000007b error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I installed python3 on my PC (Windows 7 sp1) but when I try tu run it told me first that there was a dll error, I thought I would solve it by downloading some files after googling my problem, effectively there is no dll error anymore but now there is "0xc000007b error" I searched a lot in Google and youtube but it doesn't work, how do I do please?

Comment: There are suggestions [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20650596/cannot-open-python-error-0xc000007b).

Comment: @GillesPilon If you think this question has an answer somewhere else in this site - [flag it as duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) instead of posting a link to a question as a comment...

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall it and download [Python Releases for Windows](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/). Please note that

> Note that Python 3.9.6 cannot be used on Windows 7 or earlier.