# FFmpeg and VS2010 (Debug vs Release)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ffmpeg

I 'm working on a project the requires FFmpeg libraries to extract metadata from a video a file. I' m using static builds from zeranoe (http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) . The Solution works fine in Debug mode .

But when I start it in release mode I get this error :

**"The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b).Click ok to close "**

I have no idea why .Any suggestions ?

conf :

- MS visual Studio 2010 win 32 application
- C++ lang
- Qt 4.3 used
- FFmpeg static builds
- Windows 64 bit system

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492037/the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc000007b for me this meant "you built it using MSYS2 and apparently it mixed in all sorts of weird .dll links like iconv, zlib, etc" so it was only working in the MSYS prompt but not normal DOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be about missing dependency DLLs. Your troubleshooting is to use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to check your binary and identify [missing] dependencies it require.

Possible problems with dependency DLLs include:

- **32/64 bitness mismatch of a dependency DLL**
- broken DLL itself

Note that Dependency Walker covers these as well. Also note that if you build your application with output in different folders, your Debug/Release versions of the application might be effectively using different FFmpeg (and/or other dependency) DLLs, hence different runtime behavior.

See also:

- [Now I use the automated built MinGW64 and put the .a and .h files to accordingly locatin, but the ffmpeg.exe cannot start and complained about the "The Application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)".](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=4906&sid=29aad4111dc9b91fe736608cabfc9d4f#p4906)

Comment: No the file did not report about any missing dlls .. It was a straight close now error . If there was a dll missing it would have showed 'DLL missing '  error . Also this thing works perfectly in debug mode . If there was a dll missing it wld not have worked in debug mode right ?

Comment: No, not right. And then you don't need to guess, Dependency Walker resolves the doubts.