# ffmpeg example working in debug but not in release

Tags: ffmpeg, visual-studio-2010

While running the examples about ffmpeg here :https://github.com/chelyaev/ffmpeg-tutorial  (tutorial 01 to be exact) I found that my application worked in debug mode but crashed directly in release mode. What could be the cause for this .

I am using 32 bit builds from  http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A similar problem is located here: http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=998 and I opted to setting a linker option /OPT:NOREF for my setting .I am using Qt 4.8.6 with vs2010 and specifically adding

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += /OPT:NOREF
```

to my .pro file got rid of the problem for the moment.Hope this helps somebody some day .

More on this here: http://ffmpeg.org/platform.html#Linking-to-FFmpeg-with-Microsoft-Visual-C_002b_002b

Note: A similar question is located here [FFmpeg and VS2010 (Debug vs Release)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23889979/ffmpeg-and-vs2010-debug-vs-release) but no satisfactory answer (in my opinion) has been provided.So here is my ounce of contribution to SO  ;-)