# 0xc000007b Error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-runtime

here is some information to understand my situation better.

OS: windows 8.1

IDE: Visual Studio 2008 Pro

Language: C++

i have just my Firefox reinstalled and after this(maybe it was not the reason),

my visual studio Project compiled only with 9.0.30729.6161 VC++ Runtime DLL.

Until yesterday it always compiled with 9.0.30729.8387 VC++ Runtime DLL.

Because of this (or maybe other reason), now i cannot start my Project.exe.

Nothing is changed in source-code. Project-Property and all other things are also unchanged.

I just get the error number 0xc000007b suddenly.

How can i fix this?

[image: error message]

Comment: "or maybe other reason" is an important insight. follow that.

Comment: the problem is.. as long as i know, i did not anything else.. i just my firefox reinstalled.. that is all i did..  what can cause this kind error?

Comment: It is *apparently* (but not at all certain) a problem with loading a DLL required by the application. If you can, take a screenshot of the error box and include it here? There might be some clue. Also try to reproduce the problem with a minimal hello world app.

Comment: i have attached the screenshot of the errror box. and i will try to make the same problem with a minimal hello world app..

Comment: In the meantime i have tried to make the same problem with a minimal hello world app.. But the minimal hello world app runs very well without any problem, although it is also compiled with 9.0.30729.6161 runtime dll.. i have no idea why this error happens to my specifig project so suddenly..

Comment: By far the most common cause of this error is a 32-bit app loading a 64-bit DLL.  Or the other way around.  If you have no idea what DLL is the trouble-maker then SysInternals' Process Monitor can show you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492037/the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc000007b)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It was because of an 32bit DLL, which should not be loaded for my 64bit Project.exe.

I have found this with Process Monitor.

I don't know why, but anyway is the "path" is changed and the 32bit DLL(which has the same name with 64bit DLL) is loaded..

If you have the same Problem, check whether there is a problem between your application and its dependencies using [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

Comment: Praps Firefox messed with your PATH. Interesting problem!

Comment: That clue helped me a lot because I had that 0x000007b issue and the problem was that my application prepared for 32bit but I used some 64bit DLL files with it .Thank you .

Answer (score 3):

Entered the answer in another place, but figure it could be helpful for folks who badly need some help:

It has been mentioned in other answers that using dependency walker is the way to go, in my case (my application keeps failing with the error code),  dependency walker showed a few dll that are NOT relevant!

Finally figured out that I can run profiling by going to "profile" menu and it will run the application and stop at the exact dll that's cause the problem!  I found out a 32bit dll was picked because of path and fixed it.

[image]

Comment: `I can run profiling by going to "profile" menu` - where is this menu, which app are you talking about?

Answer (score -9):

-Turn off your antivirus software before starting the installation.

-Accept any additional software offered during installation process, since it may be crucial for running your application properly. You can skip things such as search bars, antivirus scanners, registry cleaners and the other software which isn’t directly related to the application.

-Install an application to the system partition (C:). Although this shouldn’t matter, it’s been proven that some apps may return an error if installed on a logical partition.

There is more than one way to solve it.  This link might also be helpful.
http://finally-found-the-solution.blogspot.com/2015/02/how-to-fix-0xc000007b-application-error.html

Comment: Canned responses from front-line IT support are not appropriate here. This is a website for professional software developers who expect a little more than "have you tried turning it off and on again?".

Comment: Also you've plagiarised this text. You didn't write it. It comes from the site you linked to, but you gave no indication that it's a quote. That's bad.