# 0xc000007b error and Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86 Runtime

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++-runtime

Currently, we need to provide a windows client for our game user.
It works fine after we compile it with vs2010 on our development machine.
But when we send it to other pc,  it has this 0x000007b error.
It is very similar to this question: [0xc000007b Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28299246/0xc000007b-error)

I figure out that:
It works fine if we have vs2010 and this
[image: runtime]
on that pc(not ok even when 2010 x86 Redistributable has been installed).

How can I install this 2010 x86 Runtime to our user's pc or what can I do to avoid this 0x000007b error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Visual Studio 2003 => 2010 used .net assembly technology to allow for side by side installation of different Visual Studio binaries.

This mechanism had some advantages

1. More likely to get updated with critical fix, by updating a global copy, which would be used by your app
2. Better security - would only load Microsoft signed dll.

It also had complexities of understanding.

### Your choices

1. Install using merge modules - these are reference counted, and should mean the global system gets the correct version
2. Install using redist files - find the correct version of the redistributable exe, and distribute and run that.  If other people run this, and then uninstall it, it removes tour copy too.
3. Install to your application local folder.

I would recommend install to your application local folder - this means the files are completely under your control.  See [msdn : deploy to local folder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293565(v=vs.100).aspx)