Running an application made with Visual Studio 2022 on another pc
Application will not run on another person's PC.  I've already done some troubleshooting on my own.  Everything I've tried is written below.  If there's something I'm not thinking of I would be grateful for any suggested solutions.
The application is written in c++ on Visual studio 2022.  I gave a copy of my project to someone I know.  The exe wouldn't run.  All dll files that are required to run it are in the same folder as the exe.  The application is 64 bit and all dlls that I've placed in there to my knowledge are 64bit as well.  The project was built on my computer which is running windows 10.  The person I gave the project to is running windows 11.  The error code I'm being given is 0xc000007b.

Do you get a popup saying anything? Have the other system installed the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable?

that's likely a missing C++ runtime .... the other PC needs to install Visual C++ 2015-2022 redistributable package ... or update the system using windows updates (which i think should install it).

They have installed the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable already.  It still hasn't worked.

okay, have them download dependency walker and see what dlls are missing.

Alright I will have them try that.

I would also like to mention that earlier when it was installed on their computer they tried to run the application only for it to tell them there were missing dlls.  The error code I've been given now is after I had them move the dlls required into that same folder.  In other words, if a dll file were missing wouldn't the application have thrown an error and told them about it?  I'm having them check with dependency walker anyway but this is mostly just for my own curiosity.

@MatthewSpringer could be related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28299246/0xc000007b-error , you could have shipped wrong dlls, or you could have shipped a debug build and the redistributable package only has release binaries.

Since I haven't been able to figure out how to build MSI packages, I generally just resort to changing the Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library from "Multi-threaded (Debug) DLL" to just "Multi-threaded (Debug)". Same with other libs, to ideally only have dependencies on system-DLLs.

Changing from debug to release did it!  Thanks so much all!
