# c++ programs on computers without visual studios

Tags: visual-c++, sfml, software-distribution

My friend and I are making a game using C++ and the sfml graphics library. We are almost done, but every time we manually put the .exe (and necessary assets) on a computer that doesn't have visual studios installed it gives an error. The error is: The program can't start because MSVCP120D.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem. After making a copy of the .dll file and placing it in the local application folder, it came up with another error: The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). I've seen a few posts on stack over flow and other resources, but the questions are usually lacking in detail and go unanswered.

Comment: Only ever deploy the Release build of your program.  And don't copy the wrong file, you probably got that one from c:\windows\system32.  Look in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\redist for the correct one, pay attention to the platform target.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the [Visual C++ Redistributable Package for Visual Studio 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=40784) (VC++ v12) and install it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We have downloaded the package, but are unsure how to implement it. Can you point me in the direction of a tutorial or personal insight in to how to use the package?

Comment: You simply install it on the machine you wish to run your program on. It  provides the run-time execution environment for VC++ programs to run without having VS installed.

Comment: After doing that, we still got the "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)" error.

Comment: What other dependencies are you using? [Here is another SO question and answer which may help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492037/the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc000007b).

Comment: So, we are using the standard **kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib** in addition to the sfml dependencies. We tried using dependency walker per the Q&A you linked to, but it seemed to not be the answer we are looking for.