# Xampp - Apache Not starting and throwing an error

Tags: apache, xampp

I have installed xampp in my pc,
i am trying to install apache services through cmd, also if i try to start the apache service from xampp control, it throws ans error that `"The Application was unable to start correctly (0xc00007b);`

i have tried to install a .net framework as some people suggested but still same error.

my cmd command to start apache

D:\xampp\apache\bin>httpd -k install

Any body knows the solution for the same?

Comment: Your post is a bit confusing, at least to me.  First you state you are trying to install the service, then you say when you start the service it throws an error.  So it must be installed, but not working properly.

The next part of the post lists your command to start apache, but the -k install switch is to install the service.  To start apache it would be httpd -k start.

See if this post helps:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492037/the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc000007b]

Comment: You are installing xampp but you are not using its control panel to start?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 x86](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145).

After that, reboot your computer and try again. If the apache is still not starting, run the XAMPP control panel as administrator.

In case that you're using Skype, make sure the tick allowing it to use ports 80 and 443 is not selected.

Comment: how am I going to know that Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 is installed in my PC. Looking at the control panel?

Comment: Usually yes, depending on the version of your Windows.

Comment: if I show you an image snaphot of he cpanel will you be a able to tell if I have the correct visual C installed?I am facing a similar problem

Comment: why don't try to install it directly?

Comment: maybe it is already installed...that is why i said to take a look at an image snapshot

Answer (score 0):

I installed the last version of Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable , and then rebooted my PC and the problem resolved .