# Xampp will not work because of this error(0xc000007b)

Tags: xampp

I have a problem. XAMPP will not start Apache. I have tried all the recommended solutions, and they do not work. I still get this error(0xc000007b). This question did not help me: [Xampp - Apache Not starting and trowing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38485559/xampp-apache-not-starting-and-trowing-error)

What is a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing Xampp 5.6.31 instead of any Xampp 7.0 or 7.1 version. This will definitely work. :)

Comment: Way ahead of you.

Answer (score 0):

This is an underlying problem with Windows. You need to make sure you have all updates installed, and specifically that .NET is up to date. Frankly a reformat (if that's a simple matter for you) is likely the best way to be rid of it once and for all.

Comment: The last time I experienced this problem, I wound up simply reinstalling windows from scratch (the way I am set up, that is not very difficult to accomplish). The problem did not occur after that.