# How to fix exit value -1,073,741,701 in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get C++ to work in NetBeans, the code builds fine but then throws

> RUN FAILED (exit value -1,073,741,701, total time: 125ms).

How do I fix this?

I reinstalled the Cygwin compiler for 32 bit, and remapped the environment variables.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Hi";
    return 0;
}
```

Result: RUN FAILED (exit value -1,073,741,701, total time: 125ms)
Expected: Hi

Comment: BTW, `-1,073,741,701` is ‭`0xC000007B‬` which I believe means your are missing a dll or have a dll conflict perhaps have the wrong 32 / 64 bit dll in the path. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492037/the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc000007b