# C++ SDL "Native' has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b)"

Tags: c++, sdl

My Code

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include <iostream>
#undef main

int main ( void ) {
SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );
SDL_Quit(  );
return 0;
}
```

I followed LazyFoo's tut, but I still needed to modify my settings even to build the solution.
Now, every time I debug it I get this:

The program `[11228] xxx.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b).`

Can you help me please ?

edit: I'm running Windows 7 64bit, and I've the x86 lib package included, linker inputs: SDL.lib;SDLmain.lib;SDL_image.lib;OpenGL32.lib;glu32.lib

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried the suggestions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9223611/using-sdl-image-in-visual-studio-2010-with-error-application-was-unable-to-sta)?

The error you're seeing usually indicates that a runtime dll can't be found. If you *have* already tried the above, perhaps you could open the built executable in [depends.exe](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) which should let you know which DLLs are missing.

Answer (score 2):

The error also means you might be mixing architectures: 64bit app with 32 bit libraries or (more common:) vice versa

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will help you. I have run into the same error with OpenCv. It turned out that I was linking the x64 DLLs instead of the x86 DLLs.