# SDL/C IMG_Load triggers 0xc000007b error

Tags: c, image, sdl

I'm following the LazyFoo's SDL Tutorial with C (not CPP) and I'm stuck at the part where I switch from SDL_LoadBMP() to IMG_Load(). The function

```
SDL_Surface *load_image(char *filename) {

    SDL_Surface* loadedImage = NULL;
    SDL_Surface* optimizedImage = NULL;

    loadedImage = SDL_LoadBMP(filename);

    if(loadedImage != NULL) {
        optimizedImage = SDL_DisplayFormat( loadedImage );

        SDL_FreeSurface(loadedImage);
    }

    return optimizedImage;
}
```

Works just fine with

`background = load_image("background.bmp");`

but if I change

`loadedImage = SDL_ImageBMP(filename);`

it to

`loadedImage = IMG_Load(filename);`

and build/run it triggers the 0xc000007b error. I'm pretty sure I installed the SDL_image.h library properly cause I followed the steps carefuly. So my question is: what's wrong? From google I've come only to: something with .dll's but - what? I'm using Visual Studio 2010, but it happens with Code::Blocks as well (but there it just won't compile)

Comment: Shouldn't `SDL_ImageBMP` read `SDL_LoadBMP`?

Comment: Lots of questions about this error, just type 0xc000007b in the search box at the upper right of this page.

Comment: Just go to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9241557/1077364

Answer (score -1):

take the SDL.dll

from the sdl you downloaded

(from http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-devel-1.2.15-VC.zip) and paste it alongside of the executable.

Try the one in the lib/x86 folder

then remove any SDL.dll file you may have pasted in System32/ or System/ or SysWOW64/ during your sdl installing process