# SDL Initialization ERROR

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, sdl

I had have some problems to setup the SDL on my PC .

I already copy all DLL fonts  to the folders System32 or SysWOW64 (I've tried both). And make the all the setup in Visual Studio 2012, but when I try to initialize the SDL one error appers:

The program '[8184] "MyProject".exe' has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b). ?

It happens when I try to include SDL.h on my cpp file:

```
#include <SDL.h>

int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
    //Start SDL
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );

    //Quit SDL
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9223611/using-sdl-image-in-visual-studio-2010-with-error-application-was-unable-to-sta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post bellow answers my request

http://www.gamedev.net/topic/632552-sdl-pisses-me-off/

Resuming you should point to the SDL X86 lib on: Project->Properties->VC++ Directories->Library Directories

I was pointing to X64 =)

Good Bye!