# Dev IL linking and compiling error (0xc000007b)

Tags: c++, opengl, linker, assimp, devil

I'm trying to make this project work [Link to Lighthouse](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/cg-topics/code-samples/importing-3d-models-with-assimp/)

---

**First a bunch of info:**

I'm using:
Windows 7 Pro 64-bit and Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate

 (Project on default settings which I believe is 32-bit)

**About libraries:**
**DevIL:** I downloaded and installed this one [DevIL 1.7.8 SDK for 32-bit Windows](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/openil/DevIL-SDK-x86-1.7.8.zip) 
**Assimp:** assimp--3.0.1270-sdk

**Project settings:**
**Platform:** Active(Win32)
**Configuration:** All Configurations
**Library Directories:**
C:\assimp--3.0.1270-sdk\lib\assimp_release-dll_win32;C:\DevIL\lib
**Include Directories:**
C:\assimp--3.0.1270-sdk\include;C:\DevIL\include
**Library Directories:**
C:\assimp--3.0.1270-sdk\lib\assimp_release-dll_win32;C:\DevIL\lib
**C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories:**
C:\assimp--3.0.1270-sdk\include;C:\DevIL\include
**Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies:**
%(AdditionalDependencies)

---

OK, now when I compile my project I receive error:

```
Application was unable to start correctly(0xc000007b)
The program '[16912] AssimpModelImport Demo.exe' has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b)
```

---

By commenting out lines of code (cant debug) I've found out where the error occurs:

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

#include <IL\il.h>


#include "assimp/Importer.hpp"
#include "assimp/PostProcess.h"
#include "assimp/Scene.h"

#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


#ifdef _WIN32
#pragma comment(lib,"glew32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"assimp.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "DevIL.lib")
#endif

[...] bunch of functions [...]

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    [...]
        IlInit(); // DevIL initialisation // ERROR
    [...]   
}
```

Anyone knows what's happening here? How can I solve this?
I want to use parts of this code to render 3D *.OBJ models in my OpenGL 3.3 project.

---

**If it's needed, here's my debug log:**

```
'AssimpModelImport Demo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\L3DAssimpModelImport Demo\Release\AssimpModelImport Demo.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'AssimpModelImport Demo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AssimpModelImport Demo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AssimpModelImport Demo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AssimpModelImport Demo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Bitdefender\Antivirus Free Edition\avc3\avc3_sig_271\avcuf32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AssimpModelImport Demo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\L3DAssimpModelImport Demo\Release\freeglut.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
'AssimpModelImport Demo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AssimpModelImport Demo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AssimpModelImport Demo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AssimpModelImport Demo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AssimpModelImport Demo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AssimpModelImport Demo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AssimpModelImport Demo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AssimpModelImport Demo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AssimpModelImport Demo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AssimpModelImport Demo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AssimpModelImport Demo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\opengl32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AssimpModelImport Demo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\glu32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AssimpModelImport Demo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ddraw.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AssimpModelImport Demo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dciman32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AssimpModelImport Demo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\setupapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AssimpModelImport Demo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AssimpModelImport Demo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AssimpModelImport Demo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AssimpModelImport Demo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AssimpModelImport Demo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AssimpModelImport Demo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AssimpModelImport Demo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp120.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AssimpModelImport Demo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr120.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AssimpModelImport Demo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\L3DAssimpModelImport Demo\Release\Assimp32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AssimpModelImport Demo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_50934f2ebcb7eb57\msvcp90.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AssimpModelImport Demo.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.6161_none_50934f2ebcb7eb57\msvcr90.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The program '[19340] AssimpModelImport Demo.exe' has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the error is not a compiler or linker error.  That error is a runtime error.

You are running a 32-bit application, but the `SysWOW64` directory indicates you're attempting to load 64-bit components for the 32-bit program.  This of course will not work.

There could be several reasons for the error, but the first one you should inspect are your project settings.  Maybe somewhere `x64` is being used, causing a dependency on the 64-bit DLL's to be encountered.

If all else fails, please use a program such as Dependency Walker http://www.dependencywalker.com/

and inspect your EXE file to ensure it is a 32-bit executable, and also to view the dependent DLL's.

Comment: Oh my god. I just found out that that i actually placed the 64-bit  Devil.dll into my Release folder where exe is placed. I've replaced it with 32-bit from DevilSDK and now it works! http://puu.sh/d8We1/7b65007aa7.png
I'm so happy! Thank you so much Paul! Have a wonderful life and I wish you to be the happiest person on earth! Thank you!